# *WHY* does Kali boot up with its screen upside down?

Tags: virtualbox, multi-boot, kali-linux

I'm kinda new to Kali-Linux. I'm multi-booting on my Laptop with Windows, Ubuntu and Kali. Every time I boot up Kali, starting from the login screen, everything is upside down. I've managed to "fix" this by doing `xrandr -o normal` **every time** I log in to Kali. So far, it stays normal until I log out or shutdown.

However, I'm also running a Kali VM on Virtualbox. There's no multi-booting on that VM. Kali boots up right (and upright) every time, never seem to get the upside down screen.

I'm not sure what the reason for the upside-down screen is. Many people seem to have encountered this problem and I've installed Kali on my laptop several times (dual-booting on the main machine, not the VM) and the same upside-down screen thing happens every time.

The main differences seem to be:

- Running directly on an actual laptop VS Running on a VM (virtualbox)
- Multi-booting alongside 2 other OS's VS solo-booting

What are some possible reasons and (permanent) fixes for this upside-down screen on Kali?

Comment: Kali is known for trouble with graphic card drivers. If you install Kali on your laptop, then you are not using for penetration testing. So read [this](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me), and instead of trying to fix Kali, I'd recommend to just install all the hacking tools Kali has on Ubuntu, and to use this instead of Kali. Kali is **not** "what the experts use" or "what all the hackers use", no matter what you read on some forums.

Comment: Does the laptop have an accelerometer? What is the laptop's model? What desktop environment are you using in Kali and in Ubuntu?